# Unable to import python packages (already installed) in jupyter notebook RPi3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyter notebook in Raspberry Pi3. I have already installed pandas and other packages. My python3 IDLE can import all those packages but jupyter always shows an error saying

> No module named pandas

Tried lots of things but none of them are working.

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter --upgrade 
sudo pip3 install ipykernel --upgrade

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 list
Package                       Version    
----------------------------- -----------
alabaster                     0.7.12     
appdirs                       1.4.3      
asn1crypto                    0.24.0     
astroid                       2.1.0      
asttokens                     1.1.13     
attrs                         19.1.0     
automationhat                 0.1.0      
Babel                         2.7.0      
backcall                      0.1.0      
beautifulsoup4                4.7.1      
bleach                        3.1.0      
blinker                       1.4        
blinkt                        0.1.2      
bokeh                         1.2.0      
buttonshim                    0.0.2      
Cap1xxx                       0.1.3      
certifi                       2018.8.24  
chardet                       3.0.4      
Click                         7.0        
cloudpickle                   1.2.1      
colorama                      0.3.7      
colorzero                     1.1        
cookies                       2.2.1        
HeapDict                      1.0.0      
html5lib                      1.0.1      
idna                          2.6        
imagesize                     1.1.0      
ipykernel                     5.1.1      
ipyparallel                   6.2.4      
ipython                       7.5.0      
ipython-genutils              0.2.0      
ipywidgets                    7.4.2      
isort                         4.3.4      
itsdangerous                  0.24       
jedi                          0.13.2     
Jinja2                        2.10       
jsonschema                    3.0.1      
jupyter                       1.0.0      
jupyter-client                5.2.4      
jupyter-console               6.0.0      
jupyter-core                  4.5.0      
keyring                       17.1.1     
keyrings.alt                  3.1.1      
kiwisolver                    1.0.1      
lazy-object-proxy             1.3.1      
locket                        0.2.0      
logilab-common                1.4.2      
lxml                          4.3.2        
packaging                     19.0       
pandas                        0.24.2     

import pandas as pd

ImportError: No modules named pandas
```

Comment: have you checked which python version your jupyter notebook is using compared. Is it the same as the IDLE ?

Comment: yes.. kernel in jupyter is using python 3 and idle3 is installed

Comment: compare the output of `print(sys.path)` are they the same?

Comment: nope.. not same

Comment: then they are not using the same python installation. Do you maybe have multiple versions installed or virtual environments?

Comment: Python 2 and 3 both are installed... please suggest a solution by which I don’t lose my data

Comment: can you add the outputs of `print(sys.path)` and `print(sys.executable)` to your question? Then we can get an idea of your system configuration

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_NXHcQMXX9En3yJRpRwRvijpSK1axrIO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "kernel in jupyter is using python 3" --> obviously not. It is using python 2.7

Comment: what should i do so that it uses python 3???

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zGJaCAIwJ8-JLig962wA3H_Fk-l1K1Hu/view?usp=sharing

if this helps

Comment: Your problem is that you probably also have an installation of jupyter for your python2 and that probably takes preference when you jsut type `jupyter` in your terminal. I guess you could modify your `PATH` or use `pip uninstall jupyter` to uninstall the python2.7 version

Comment: try using Docker on RPi3 to run Jupyter Notebooks. https://hub.docker.com/r/andresvidal/jupyter-armv7l